# JavaScript regex find instances

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a long string and I need to find instances of `'#!#'+some text+'#!#'` right now I have:

```
string.replace(/(#!#*#!#)/g, 
      function (m) {....});
```

I need the whole thing passed into a function like that so that I can replace them correctly.

However, I want `m` to only be equal to what lies between the two `#!#`

```
#!#I want this part#!#
```

but what I return needs to replace the entire `'#!#'+some text+'#!#'`.

If it matters the text between the two `#!#`s will be either an integer or a sentence, but it won't contain the pattern `#!#` of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/(#!#*#!#)/
```

Close, but the `*` makes it mean “a number of instances of `#`, which is probably not what you meant. Try:

```
/#!#(.*?)#!#/
```

(The `*?` means match as little as possible up to the `#!#`. Otherwise, if there are two `#!#` sequences, the expression will match `greedily` up to the last one.)

Comment: Note that the arguments to the replace function will be the whole matched string (including the #!#'s) then the part between the #!#'s.

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse again when you get the "big" word, like so

```
"llala #!#11#!# asdad".replace(/#!#(.*?)#!#/gi, function(m) { return m.match(/#!#(.*?)#!#/)[1];})
```